# Converting a list to a dictionary troubles

Tags: python, dictionary

I am reading lines from a file and appending each line to a list. This is fine, however I am having trouble going from 
['A','B', 'C', 'D', ... 'last element'], ['A','B','C','D', ...'last element'], .... 
to {'A':['B','C','D', ... 'last element'], ....} 
I can separate the key I want in each line, but when I try to convert it to a dictionary it goes 
{'A':['last element'], ...}

```
ct = 0
myKey = eachList[0]

for el in eachList:
    subList = []
    if ct != 0:
        subList.append(eachList[ct])
        myDict[myKey] = subList
    ct+=1
```

I searched the forum, but the topics were either using ittertools/ izip or I just couldn't follow. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Where do you define subList?

Comment: Didn't notice the double ListList, corrected it just above my if statement.

Comment: Could you give next items in result dictionary? `{'A':['B','C','D', ... 'last element'], ....}`

Comment: You're redefining `subList = []` every iteration through the loop, so of course it will start as empty. Define it outside the loop. Anyway, you might want to use a `collections.defaultdict(list)`

Comment: Basically it does the same thing for each list. It will go through each list, separate the key, but only append the last element to the dictionary. So it would go {.., 'E':['last element'],..} it keeps replacing the current element, with the next element, then finally keeps the last element in eachList.

Comment: That did it David! Thank you for your help I was getting frustrated with this I am still new to programming.

Comment: @user3591798 You also could make counter `ct` using `enumerate` keyword: `for ct, el in enumerate(eachList):` that's make your code more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet of code, how you can simply read lines into a dictionary:

```
final_dict = {}

with open('text.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        raw = line.strip().split(',')
        final_dict[raw[0]] = raw[1:]
```

Given the following input:

```
k1, v11, v12, v13
k2, v21, v22, v23
k3, v31, v32, v33
```

`final_dict` will be:

```
 {'k3': [' v31', ' v32', ' v33'], 'k2': [' v21', ' v22', ' v23'], 'k1': [' v11', ' v12', ' v13']}
```